# Laravel 5.6 Migration Error

Tags: laravel, mysqli, laravel-5.6

I have created the migration file to manage the menu items for my new project. Here is the migration file.

```
Schema::create('menu_items', function (Blueprint $table) {            
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('menugroup_id',10);
            $table->string('name',100)->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', ['page_link','internal_link','external_link'])->nullable();
            $table->string('link')->nullable();
            $table->integer('page_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();
            $table->enum('active',['1','0'])->nullable();
            $table->integer('lft')->nullable();
            $table->integer('rgt')->nullable();
            $table->integer('depth')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps(); 
            $table->foreign('menu_group_id')->references('id')->on('menu_groups')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Following error occurred, while running migration command.

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `menu_items` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `menugroup_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(100) null, `type` enum('page_link', 'internal_link', 'external_link') null, `link` varchar(255) null, `page_id` int null, `parent_id` int null, `active` enum('1', '0') null, `lft` int null, `rgt` int null, `depth` int null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

  at /var/www/html/xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|
```

I am unable to understand why this error is occurred because i haven't set any auto incremented fields apart from id. If the post is duplication i am happy to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('menugroup_id',10);
```

To:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('menu_group_id',10);
```

Comment: At least we found a mistake. :D

Answer (score 1):

Change:
`$table->unsignedInteger('menugroup_id',10);`

To:
`$table->unsignedInteger('menugroup_id');`

The documentation tells that the second variable is to turn on/off the auto_increment and because you already use `$table->increments('id');` it breaks.

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_unsignedInteger

**UPDATE**
Also you have 2 diffrend names `menugroup_id` when you make the field and you try to make a foreign key with `menu_group_id`